# Modify div when determinated span is selected

Tags: javascript, html

I need to modify the second div code when, for example, the value of the first span is BMW.
Like:

```
if ("<span class="current required" name="macchina" required="">BMW</span> == true"){
code here;
}
```

Code from the site:

```
<div class="nice-select" tabindex="0">
<span class="current required" required="">BMW</span>
<ul id="macchina" class="list">
<li data-value="ZERO" value="ZERO" name="ZERO" class="option focus">Seleziona la marca della macchina</li><li data-value="BMW" value="BMW" name="BMW" class="option selected">BMW</li>
<li data-value="Ferrari" value="Ferrari" name="Ferrari" class="option">Ferrari</li>
<li data-value="Toyota" value="Toyota" name="Toyota" class="option">Toyota</li>
</ul>
</div>

.
.
.
.

<div class="nice-select" tabindex="0">
<span class="current required" required=""></span>
<ul id="macchina" class="list"></ul>
<li data-value="ZERO" value="ZERO" name="ZERO" class="option focus">Seleziona il modello della macchina</li>
</div>
```

Comment: It is hard to understand what you are trying to do.  Are you trying to check the **text** of the span, "BMW" in this case?

Comment: @Don'tPanic yes is what i trying to check

Answer (score 0):

Use innerHTML to get and change the text.

```js
var value = document.getElementById("span1").innerHTML;

if (value === 'BMW') {
  document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = 'BMW has been selected';
}
```

```html
<span class="current required" id="span1" required="">BMW</span>

<div class="nice-select" id="div1" tabindex="0">
```

Answer (score 0):

One alternative would be to use `querySelectorAll` and iterate through all your `.nice-select` elements, finding the ones that match the conditions and executing the desired code accordingly.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.nice-select').map((divElement) => {
  var modify = false;
  for (var el of divElement.children) {
    if (el.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'span' && el.innerText.toLowerCase() == 'bmw') {
      modify = true;
    }
  }
  if (modify) {
    // ...code to execute when conditions are met
  }
});
```

Comment: it doesn't works...

Comment: @NicolòPietroOggiano this should work for all elements with the class `nice-select` that have a span element containing the text BMW... which part isn't working exactly?

Comment: if i add, for example, "alert("ciao");"
like:
 if (modify) { 
alert("ciao");
  }
it doesn't works when i select BMW